# LINQ: How to select item elements where child node satisfies condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My XML looks something like this:

```
 <order>
    <order_number>1N</order_number>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>11/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Joe</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>12/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Mike</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>8/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Steve</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
</order>
<order>
    <order_number>2N</order_number>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>11/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Rob</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>12/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Marko</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>8/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Sam</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
</order>
<order>
    <order_number>3N</order_number>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>11/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Nick</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>12/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Ashley</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
    <execution_data>
        <exe_date>8/01/2011</exe_date>
        <exe_name>Marc</exe_name>
    </execution_data>
</order>


    public class ExecutionItem
    {
       public string Date {get;set;}
       public string Name {get;set;}
    }

    public class Response
    {
       public List<ExecutionItem> ExecutionItems{get;set;}
    }
```

How to select an  order where `order_number` equals `1N`and then get all `execution_data` from that order using LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two approaches here:

- You could find all `<order_number>` elements with a value of `1N`, then find all sibling `execution_data` elements
- You could find `order` elements with a relevant `order_number` element, and then find the child `execution_data` elements.

I'd probably pick the latter approach which would be something like:

```
var executionDataElements = 
      doc.Descendants("order")
         .Where(order => (string) order.Element("order_number") == "1N")
         .SelectMany(order => order.Elements("execution_data");
```

(Note that if this matches more than one order, you'll get all the elements from all matching orders.)

The first approach *if* you know that `execution_data` elements come after the `order_number` element, and if you know that there's only one such `order_number` element, would be:

```
var executionDataElements = doc.Descendants("order_number")
                               .First(x => (string) x == "1N")
                               .ElementsAfterSelf("execution_data");
```